# error in displaying colors in DVG when using primary colors or any words?

Tags: c#, winforms

in my winform it was look like this

[image]

and now in my actual database was this one without the cellformating
[image]

now my problem was if my color picker trying to insert in the database an primary or any words color like #red,#blue,#yellow i was getting an error on my cellformating event..so how do i catch that error using try catch or anything that might resolve my problem??

my code for cell formatting

```
private void dataGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
    {
        //Check if we're formatting the color column
        if (this.dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "color")
        {
            //Make sure there's a value set
            if (e.Value != null)
            {
                string colorCode = (string)e.Value;
                ColorConverter cc = new ColorConverter();
                e.CellStyle.BackColor = (Color)cc.ConvertFromString("#" + colorCode);
                //If you don't want the code to show
                e.Value = "";
                e.FormattingApplied = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can verify the code string with [IsValid()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.colorconverter.isvalid(v=vs.110).aspx) method:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    //Check if we're formatting the color column
    if (this.dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "color")
    {
        //Make sure there's a value set
        if (e.Value != null)
        {
            string colorCode = (string)e.Value;
            ColorConverter cc = new ColorConverter();
            if(!cc.IsValid(colorCode))
                 colorCode = "#" + colorCode;

            e.CellStyle.BackColor = (Color)cc.ConvertFromString(colorCode);
            //If you don't want the code to show
            e.Value = "";
            e.FormattingApplied = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: your code was working but some of my colors are changed after reloading?

Comment: whats your mean some colors changed? can you add some example?

Comment: here's some screenshots http://www.mediafire.com/download/t5s2ng776gu607m/before_and_after.rar

Comment: I saw your screenshot, but still didn't get what's the problem?